# Getting updates from Ardunio with PySerial only every 2 minutes instead of 1 minute

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I have an Arduino that reports time (in seconds), voltage, current and joules ever 60 seconds.  In the serial monitor like this:

```
time,voltage,current,joules
60,1.45,0.39,0.57
120,1.45,0.39,1.13
180,1.45,0.39,1.70
240,1.45,0.39,2.26
...
```

However the following python script I don't get this result:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
logfile = open("batterytest.log", 'w')
while True:
    if ser.readline() == b'Test Complete!':
        logfile.close()
        exit()
    logfile.write(ser.readline().decode("utf-8"))
    logfile.flush()
```

Instead I see results every 120 seconds:

```
time,voltage,current,joules
120,1.13,0.02,0.05
240,1.13,0.02,0.09
360,1.13,0.02,0.14
480,1.13,0.02,0.19
....
```

Comment: You are reading twice, so every iteration will consume two lines.

Comment: Yes, as @KlausD. said, the first read is in `if ser.readline() == b'Test Complete!':` and the second at `logfile.write(ser.readline().decode("utf-8"))`. Store the read line in a temporary string.

Comment: Everyon was right.  I don't know why that didn't occur to me when I was looking at the code.  I modified as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it may miss the in-between data point due to some timing issue. You can try to use putty to see if your arduino in fact output the right data points.

For your PySerial program, I would add a variable "data" to store your serial readline first, then perform your logic on it.

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)
logfile = open("batterytest.log", 'w') 
while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    if data == b'Test Complete!':
        logfile.close()
        exit()
    logfile.write(data.decode("utf-8"))
    logfile.flush()
```

Also, depending on your Arduino output timing, you may consider adding a timeout value for your serial read by:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600, timeout = 1 )
# Here the time out is 1 second
```